# Global variables with php in htmx

Tags: php, htmx

I have a page called **index.php** where I have a html:5 template and some php variables e.x **$lang = 'no'**.

In my index.php (which is in root) I have this:

```
<div class="card col-6" id="container">
</div>
```

and to display another page I use this:

```
<a hx-post="settings/settings.php" hx-trigger="click" hx-target="#container" hx-swap="outerHTML" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#">Settings</a>
```

The page shows as wanted, but if I try to call **$lang** inside of settings.php file I get `Warning: Undefined variable $lang`

I'm simply wondering how I can share global variables throughout my application.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create all common variable in a php file and include it in any file where you need them

Comment: Agree with above comment. Create a config file and include that in all the files that use common variables. 

If it’s framework, the. Add your variables in .env file. These days .env file is included in all of the frameworks.

Comment: Thanks alot! I'm not using any framework, is it still possible for me to use .env file and fetch data from there? @Mehmood

Comment: Added it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Well, the simplest way would be to create a env.php file and add your variables in a php array then at the end of that you add following code:

This will add the array variables in env.

```
foreach ($variables as $key => $value) {
  putenv("$key=$value");
}
```

Following function makes it easier to retrieve variables.

```
function env($key, $default = null)
{
  $value = getenv($key);
  if ($value === false) {
    return $default;
  }
  return $value;
}
```

Then include env.php file where you need the variables and access them like this.

```
env("variable");
```

This should make your life easier.